# Migration of data from old site to new

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I am working on data migration from old site to new site.

Which module i can use for data migration. I am stucked in the issue that fields are not same in the old site and new site. How can i map fields so data can be migrated from old site to new one.

**Issues that i am facing:-**

1) In old site there are lot of content types and new site there are few. Because fields are managed to merge in few content types.

2) Fields name are not same exactly same like the old site.

3) Few of the fields are converted into taxonomies.

4) Old site contain lot of data as well as images.

So is there any drupal module that i can use or i need to follow some other approach?

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 1):

From experience the [Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) can do all of this for you if you're willing to sit down and write some PHP code to define Mappings and the necessary individual migrations from/to whatever content you need.

See the project page for alot of introductory information and the `/examples` directory for sample beer data migrations.

**EDIT**

the Migrate module is a developer module which you must write PHP classes to define field mappings and source to destination content types. [Example migration classes are discussed in the official documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1006984). There is also a [Drupal 2 Drupal migration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) that provides some UI to require less custom coding.

At this time I cannot provide additional tutorials/examples -- there are many available on [google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=drupal%207%20migrate%20module%20tutorialhttp://lmgtfy.com/?q=drupal%207%20migrate%20module%20tutorial), eg:

not free:
https://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-migrate-module-series?p=1271

free 45min talk from a DrupalCamp:
http://vimeo.com/54448150

Comment: Hello @Tenken, I have tried hard to use this module but i am not able to figure this out. I don't know where i can see the option to get the data from old database/migrated data. I seen through the tutorial, it tells  we will have a tab "import from drupal" under admin/content/migrate. But i don't know how would i configure that tab to import data. Will you please explain me a little with some steps or tutorial.

Comment: hi, please see my edit.